# from scipy.linalg import _fblas: ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, eclipse, scipy, anaconda, scikit-image

I did some changes on my Anaconda installation (I just uninstalled previous one, and installed a newer version). Now trying to run my code simply importing this:

```
from skimage.measure import compare_ssim
```

But it shows this error. How can I fix it? All searching didn't help. When I do this import on Anaconda Prompt, it doesn't complaint. But when I run this on Eclipse, it shows this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\eclipse-workspace\project\hybrid.py", line 18, in <module>
    from skimage.measure import compare_ssim
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\__init__.py", line 176, in <module>
    from .util.lookfor import lookfor
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\util\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from ._montage import montage, montage2d
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\util\_montage.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .. import exposure
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\exposure\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .exposure import histogram, equalize_hist, \
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\exposure\exposure.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ..color import rgb2gray
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\color\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .colorconv import (convert_colorspace,
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\color\colorconv.py", line 59, in <module>
    from scipy import linalg
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\__init__.py", line 190, in <module>
    from .misc import *
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\misc.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .blas import get_blas_funcs
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\blas.py", line 214, in <module>
    from scipy.linalg import _fblas
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: What do you mean of procedures? I just uninstalled previous one, and installed a new one.

Comment: No, not that. I had some mixed up with conda and pip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realized when I run this import on `Anaconda Prompt`, it doesn't complaint. But when I run this on `Eclipse`, it shows this error.

The simple solution was to add this to my PATH that helped fix the problem:

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Library\bin
```

Answer (score 6):

Uninstalling and re-installing Numpy+mkl from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) fixed, in my case.

My error arised from **from scipy import signal**. But it had given the same error as yours:
"from scipy.linalg import _fblas: ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found"

Comment: How does one know which version of the scipy from that site to install - I see over 30 of them.

Comment: @guthrie I mentioned installing Numpy+mkl from that site, not scipy. For example, for 64 bit system with Python 3.8, it should be: numpy‑1.20.3+mkl‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl

Comment: @Enre Thanks, my typo/confusion, other sires had a similar recommendation for scipy. Just upgrading my python from 3.7.x to 3.8 fixed it for me.